# If autofilter gives no data move to next file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to copy the filtered data and paste. But it throws an error if there are blanks.Kindly help me on this.

This is my code. Getting an error when there are blanks for filtered criteria. Kindly suggest me what needs to be added to ignore the error and go to next file

```
Sub GetSheets()

Dim shtname As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows As Long

Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepath").Range("B2").Value
shtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepath").Range("B3").Value
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")


 Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 Sheets(shtname).Select
 Columns("A:U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

 Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
 NumRows = Application.Count(myRange)
 r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(shtname).Range("A:A"))


 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$1").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="D.C"

 ActiveSheet.Range("A2:U" & NumRows).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
 Selection.Copy

 Windows("Combined - Dc Pharmacy chargeback.xlsm").Activate

 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Kindly suggest on this

Comment: What error gets thrown? Which line?

Comment: Hi its shows an error 1004 When  there are blanks when applied criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GetSheets()

Dim shtname As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows As Long

Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepath").Range("B2").Value
shtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepath").Range("B3").Value
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

On Error Resume Next

  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 Sheets(shtname).Select
 Columns("A:U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False


  Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
  NumRows = Application.Count(myRange)
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(shtname).Range("A:A"))




ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$1").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="D.C"
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:U" & NumRows).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select



x = ActiveSheet.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

If x > 1 Then

     Selection.Copy

     Windows("Combined - Dc Pharmacy chargeback.xlsm").Activate

     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Range("A1").Select
     Selection.End(xlDown).Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

   End If
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Workbooks(Filename).Close

     Filename = Dir()



Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

An error will occur when no cells are visible. You can trap this error with `On Error Resume Next` as shown below.

```
Private Sub CopyFiltered()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                          ' last row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, "A"))

        .Range("$A$1:$U$1").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="D.C"

        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err = 0 Then
            Rng.Copy
            ' Change this address as required
            Worksheets("Manager").Cells(20, 3).Resize(Rng.Cells.Count, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0
        .ShowAllData
        Rng.AutoFilter
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `.ScreenUpdating = False` should be `True` in the end. And  instead of `Set Rng = Range` it should be `Set Rng = .Range` to trigger the `With` statement.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the ScreenUpdating setting. The `Set Range` statement is correct as it is because the cells are connected to the With statement. For reasons I haven't been able to discover I have encountered errors with the syntax you recommend, forcing me to remove the leading period. Since the syntax I used above correctly defines the sheet I have decided to avoid the leading period you would prefer to see.

Comment: interesting I apologize, you are right it works correctly even without the period. But I always used it myself with the leading period and never had issues with it.

Comment: Adding `.` as @Peh suggested is the correct way of explicitly referencing the `Range` . However, since you are using `Activesheet` it has almost no bearing since global `Range` object hooks to the `Activesheet` of the currently active workbook.

Comment: @L42 Obviously Excel (at least 2016) is doing something odd here and `Range()` is not the same as `ActiveSheet.Range()`. Instead `Range()` is smarter in guessing the correct sheet than just using the active one. If you assume `Sheet1` as active and run `ActiveSheet.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, "A"), Sheet2.Cells(5, "B")).Address(External:=True)` it throws obviously an error. But if you run `Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, "A"), Sheet2.Cells(5, "B")).Address(External:=True)` it assumes `Sheet2` instead of the active sheet which is obviously good. Non the less we should not let VBA guess and specify the sheet.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for looking into this. But this code doesnt work :(

Comment: @Sheba "*doesn't work*" is a **completely useless** error description. You won't get any further help if you just say "*doesn't work*". Always describe what is going wrong, what do you expect instead. Where you got stuck, or any errors and what error messages.

Comment: This site shows working code created in response to actual questions. If the working code that constitutes the answer  to your question was created by yourself you should post it as an answer to your question and select it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from it.